# Docker swarm mode on Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've managed to run Docker Swam mode with multiple hosts with Docker Toolbox, but I am unable to create a swarm with Docker Desktop since it apparently only offers single node swarm.

Is there any way to get this working with Docker Desktop or is it not supported?

Comment: Don't use swarm. It's an old, deprecated technology that's difficult to get help with. Use kubernetes instead. It's simpler and easier and there's a lot of support.

Comment: a. no way in hell is K8s "simpler" than swarm. b. Mirantis still supports swarm. c. Point taken however that k8s has way more support and training. d. It needs it, because k8s is a hot mess of unnecessary complication.

Comment: We have to support running the containers on a Windows host as well, and I believe K8s only runs on Linux?

Comment: I see a second misapprehension: Docker Engine is the core part of Docker that runs containers. Docker Desktop is a GUI that manages a single Docker Engine instance. That Docker Engine can have swarm mode activated. And it can be joined to, or manage, a swarm of many nodes. However, Docker Desktop is blind to that so the GUI can only be used to manage non swarm aspects of the local Docker Engine instance.
The other problem is Docker Desktop only starts its Engine instance when a user logs in. This is inappropriate for Production use. In production you want to use Docker Engine EE on Windows.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Thank you for the clarification, very much appreciated! But can I install Docker EE on Windows 7 professional (non-server version of Windows)?

Comment: I doubt it. You can try: https://docker-docs.netlify.app/install/windows/docker-ee/

Comment: Doesn't look like it's supported. Then I'm back to the only viable option being Docker Toolbox. Or just not use containers at all.. Thanks again for your help @ChrisBecke

Answer (score 1):

No. But yes. But actually no. But technically yes.

No. Docker Desktop does not support this. It manages a single docker node in a vm and has no capability to manage multiple dockers.

But yes. docker:dind is an image you can easily use to deploy multiple docker nodes as containers, and then swarm init / swarm join to create a swarm cluster hosted on docker. You can even swarm join the docker-desktop node to be the swarm manager which means you can communicate with your local docker desktop node to control the swarm.

But actually, no.
Unless your use case is a very limited hello-world on swarm tutorial, there is no support for exposing ports from the dind-swarm to the host. Even if the host docker acts as the manager, overlay networking that is required for ingress will require communications over :2377, :4789/udp, and :7946, and as the host is not part of its own overlay networks, this will never work.
So, communicating with tasks running on the swarm is basically impossible.

But technically yes. [play-with-docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com) apparently runs docker swarms using dind.  They do some heavy lifting to expose a restricted set of ports via l7 loadbalancers. Pretty cool. but not at all easy to do at home. If you have a spare Dell PowerEdge or equivalent blade server with 120+ cores just laying around, and want to expose it as a docker swarm rather than split it into VMS... perhaps this is a viable approach.

Comment: So don't bet on Docker Swarm mode with Docker Toolbox if you plan to migrate to Docker Desktop eventually?

Comment: Well, I mean, your call. Im surprised that anyone is still using Docker Toolbox. Docker Machine has been deprecated for years now, which is I assume how Toolbox manages a cluster of docker vms. As I said - PWD is a project you can literally download and run if you want swarm-in-docker, but seriously, why even chase this now? Neither Desktop nor Toolbox is used to deploy production swarms, and running a swarm on single node docker is pretty edge case. Using Desktop as a single node swarm suffices for most local application dev.

Comment: The reason I'm looking in to this is because we have some unusual customer requirements for an on-premise application: a) the current application must be split from a monolith into multiple services b) must be possible to distribute across exactly two nodes c) must run on Windows 7 and Windows 10. We could of course skip Docker completely and just develop native Windows applications and create all the infrastructure ourselves, but it sounds like a lot of work

Comment: I'm not seeing why a multi-node swarm is necessary. A single node swarm is a perfectly valid production deployment, if they have 2 host nodes (windows 7/10), then expand it to a two node docker swarm.
You NEVER want to use Docker Desktop in production as it requires a logged in user, so take advantage of the fact that all Windows server since 7 includes a docker-EE license, and requires a bit of PowerShell to activate.

Comment: But how can I run a node swarm without either Docker Toolbox OR Docker Desktop?

Comment: Windows server includes Docker EE. When activated you can use `docker` commands from the command line. `docker swarm init` will upgrade that Docker EE instance to swarm mode, and return a join token you can use to add a 2nd Windows Server Docker EE instance as a worker.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Unfortunately, these are not running the server versions of Windows

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Docker Desktop.
2. Click on the Docker icon in the system tray (Windows) or the menu bar (Mac).
3. Go to "Preferences" or "Settings."
4. In the "Kubernetes" section, you should find an option to switch to "Swarm" mode or enable Swarm mode.